# There exist a positive real number $x$ for which $x^2 < \sqrt{x}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone prove that there exists a positive real number $x$ for which $x^2< \sqrt x$

Comment: But can't real numbers include a number where 0<x<1

Comment: it's asking for any real number, and I know a number like 3/4 is a real number that fits with the case above. I just don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @M.Maric It might be easier to think about an example like "${1\over 4}$," which has an easy square root . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x<1$, then $x^2$ implies multiplying $x$ by a positive number < 1, which means $x^2 < x$. On the other hand, finding $√(x)$ implies that x is the result of multiplying some number between 0 and 1 by itself; this number must then exceed x. Since, for $0<x<1$, $x^2<x<√(x)$, $x^2<√(x)$.